# Is there an alternative task switcher to KRunner which is focused exclusively on window switching?

Tags: application-switcher, workspace-switcher, plasma-5, krunner

Currently on KDE 5 the KRunner dialogue brought up by Alt-F2 key, is not focused solely on desktop windows. It brings shortcuts to programs, search results etc, as well as the active desktop windows.

Other some alternative programs focused exclusively on window switching task, or can KRunner be configured to be restricted to desktop windows alone in certain contexts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are several routes that don't require the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> route.

## Alt+Tab

This basic method has a few possibilities itself which you can explore via `System Settings` > `Window Management` > `Task Switcher`. My preference is the very simple one shown below. On pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I have a plain text display of open windows.
[image: Alt-tab]

I keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key depressed and cycle through the choices with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. You can try various other options available on the `Task Switcher` page.

As shown in the image below, I've chosen "Text Only" from the dropdown and I have "Show selected window" unchecked. You may like something else.

[image: Text only]

## Flip windows

Open `System Settings` > `Desktop Behavior` > `Desktop Effects` and type `flip` in the search bar at the top of the page. Activate `Flip Switch`.

[image: Flip Switch]

If you click on the circled icon, you'll see a preview of what this can do. (It may take a while to load.)

If you decide you want to try it, open `System Settings` > `Shortcuts` > `Global Shortcuts` > `System Settings` and enter `flip` in the search bar (as before). Here, decide on a keyboard shortcut of choice to activate the `Flip Switch` or leave the existing choice in effect if there is one there. I've gone with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the choices and press `Enter` when you've found the one you want. (`Meta` is the `Super` or Windows key.)

[image: Flip switch in action]

## Present Windows

I won't go into detail here because the procedure to find it is the same as for `Flip Switch`. In this case, I went with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> because that was already set up. Here, as you hover over individual windows, they're highlighted and clicking on the hovered one brings it into focus.

[image: Present Windows]

---

## Using `Screen Edges`

Another thing for you to explore is `System Settings` > `Desktop Behavior` >  `Screen Edges`. Again, I'll not go into detail but just leave you with an image which I took after right-clicking on the top-right corner white square:

[image: Screen Edges]

**Edit:**

To use many of the desktop effects, you must have compositing enabled and compositing is enabled by default if your system provides it.

To check, run `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep -i composit`

My system shows:

```
$ qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep -i composit
Composite: yes; Version: 0x4
compositingMode: 1
useCompositing: true
compositingInitialized: true
windowsBlockCompositing: true
Compositing
Compositing is active
Compositing Type: OpenGL
$
```

By the way, you can toggle compositing on or off using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was looking for something entirely keyboard driven, that could set me on the right window with a few quick keystrokes, something along the `helm` dialog in emacs. but I failed to express that in  the question. I am trying to move to a 100% keyboard driven workflow even on graphical desktops, but the answer is a good answer, given the question I asked.

Comment: I like the simple text-only list your Alt-Tab method creates. How do you configure that effect?

Comment: I have no experience of Emacs, but if you describe your usage in a bit more detail, like do you prefer tabs or separate windows, and how many different applications do you run at the same time, etc there could be some options.

Comment: Oops, I was typing as you commented. Please come back in a while and I'll try to flesh out the `Alt+Tab` route.

Comment: By the way, you can "lighten" krunner substantially if you don't need all it offers. If you're interested, feel free to ask a new question on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure what KRunner searches.

Rofi is dedicated to just switching: `rofi -show window`
You and bind that to Atl Space.