# Can I have a textual Alt-Tab functionality?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, window, window-manager, application-switcher

Once upon a time there was the fabulous window manager called "enlightenment".

If you used it, and you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then you saw a small list of window titles below each other.

Like this:

- user@remote-host
- foo@db-server
- emacs
- ...

Or like this:

[image: window-switcher-simple-and-beautiful]

I liked it a lot.

I want it back. I mean the feature, not the app.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I don't want to see icons of applications like this:

[image: alt-tab-is-useless-at-the-moment]

I have up to five terminals open. If I press the windows-key I will see the roughly same image (small version of a big terminal) five times.

[image: window-key-icons]

It takes time and mental energy to find the right terminal. And I want to switch with the keyboard only, without using the mouse.

The magic behind the terminal:

```
xtermset -title foo
```

I have this the bash script which gets executed if I login via ssh.

This way I can distinguish between several terminals easily.

How to get this feature which worked in the year 1998 back?

(Please don't tell me to install the enlightenment window-manager, this question is about a simple feature, not the app)

User "DK Bose" wanted me to show the output of these commands:

```
===> wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
tguettler@aptguettler:~
===> 


tguettler@aptguettler:~
===> wmctrl -lx
0x0200000a  0 desktop_window.Nautilus  aptguettler Schreibtisch
0x01c00178  0 Pidgin.Pidgin         aptguettler tbz
0x02600010  0 Navigator.Firefox     aptguettler command line - List of window names on ALT-Tab - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
0x02200010  0 Mail.Thunderbird      aptguettler Posteingang - tguettler@tbz-pariv.de (IMAP) - Mozilla Thunderbird
0x04400006  0 gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal  aptguettler foooooo
0x044000ce  0 gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal  aptguettler tguettler@aptguettler
```

The string "foooooo" was set via `xtermset -title foooooo`. The title was set in a shell which was running ssh on a remote server.

Comment: Something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/59JH3.png?

Comment: From this and [your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1116659/480481) I am getting a feeling that somehow you've misunderstood the application-switching feature or using it wrong. Ideally there should *not* be five terminal *icons* for five terminal windows. <Alt><Tab> switches between applications whereas <Alt><key-above-Tab> switches between windows of the same application. If you use <Alt><key-above-Tab> you should see small *window previews* with window titles, à la https://i2.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/gnome-app-switcher-1.jpeg

Comment: @pomsky, I stole it from my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1085193/248158. It's one of many defaults in Kubuntu 18.04 and is not an add-on.

Comment: @DKBose yes, the screenshot looks very nice. More is not needed. Simple and beautiful :-)

Comment: @pomsky you say I have misunderstood something. Maybe I have. I have a goal. I want something to be the way I want it to be. My question is now: How to get to my goal? I don't care for the strategy (the way to get there). I would even pay, if this would help.

Comment: Could you explain what behaviour you're seeing (better with screenshots)? Because what you described (seemingly) as the default behaviour ("*same icon five times*") doesn't sound normal, window titles should also be shown by default (please read my previous comment completely). Also I presume *your goal* is to achieve something similar to the screenshot by DK, is that correct?

Comment: @pomsky yes you are right. "same icon" was wrong wording. I updated it: "I will see the roughly same image (small version of a big terminal) five times."

Comment: @pomsky yes, the screenshot by DK is what I would like ALT-TAB to look like.

Comment: @DKBose I hope that some window manager offers the simple listing.

Comment: @DKBose why should I write the output of these commands?

Comment: @DKBose I added the output of the commands to the question.

Comment: @DKBose yes, there is no xterm. Why should there be one. I use the default terminal. I guess this is gnome-terminal. What are you missing? Why should there be a xterm?

Comment: @DKBose there is an image in the question. And if you able to read then the image is already superflous.

Comment: That image is mine! You haven't posted what *you* see on *your* system.

Comment: @DKBose yes, you are right. I added two screenshots to make it more obvious what I see. It is just the default.

Comment: @guettli Curious if you tried the answe(s). Any comments? Issues?

Comment: @guettli I'm just curious, does a potential solution have to be bound to Alt+Tab ? There's a few existing applications that provide list of window names and ability to raise/focus those windows.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I guess I use Alt+Tab since Windows95. With other words: Yes, I want it to be bound to Alt+Tab

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure it's advisable to attempt to change the window manager in Ubuntu 18.04. The window manager is integrated into GNOME Shell.

You may find [*Rofi*](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi) suitable for the purpose you describe while leaving the system's default intact.

[image: Rofi in window switcher mode]

- *Rofi* is available in the universe section.
- It has an installed size of 524 kB and and very few dependencies which you can see by running `apt show rofi` or by simulating its install using `apt install -s rofi`.
- *Rofi* has several functions but the one of interest here is the window switcher.

Once *Rofi* is installed:

- Run `rofi -dump-config > ~/.config/rofi/config.rasi` to generate a local *config* file which you can modify to suit your needs.
- Preview the theme you'd like to use by running `rofi-theme-selector`. If you want to tweak the theme further, you could copy the theme over from */usr/share/rofi/themes* to *~/.local/share/rofi/themes* and give it a new name to avoid confusion. I like *Pop-Dark* and named the local version *myPop-Dark*. In the images posted in this answer, I've used *myPop-Dark*.

**Usage**

To demonstrate *Rofi's* use as an alternative to the system's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

- I opened several windows including five xterm windows.
- I assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as a shortcut keyboard combination to run `rofi -show window -theme myPop-Dark`

In the image posted above, there are three columns. If you always want only the name of the application and the title of the window, edit *~/.config/rofi/config.rasi* to change the commented out *window-format* line to

```
window-format: "{n}    {t}";
```

You can also modify the width, the height, and the location of the *rofi* window.

To bring the window you want into focus, use the arrow keys or your mouse pointer to highlight the entry and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you have a really long list of windows, press a key that's unique to the window you want to filter out all other windows. If that's not possible, filter the entries by typing, as in the animation below, <kbd>f</kbd>, followed by <kbd>o</kbd> to limit the list to windows containing the string "foo".

The animation below illustrates that.

[image: filtering windows]

To close a highlighted window, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: The link was initial broken. I updated the answer. To make AskU happy I added more characters. Unfortunately I can't remove them again. useless constraint. Sometimes patches containing on changed character are important - useless feature of AskU

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu, including 18.04, is now based on GNOME and some additional features could be made available via [GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/). Go to the website and search: use "window switcher" as keywords and the relevant extension may be listed in the first page of search result.

[This one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/973/switcher/) seems relevant and maintained:

> **Switcher** by dlandau
>
> [image: switcher by dlandau in action]
>
> Switch windows or launch applications quickly by typing
>
> Use the configured global hotkey (Super+w by default) to open a list
> of current windows. Type a part of the name or title of the
> application window you want to activate and hit enter or click on the
> item you wish to activate. You can use the arrow keys to navigate
> among the filtered selection and type several space separated search
> terms to filter further. Use Esc or click anywhere outside the
> switcher to cancel.
>
> Use the configured global hotkey (Super+x by default) to open the
> application launcher. Type a part of the name of the application you
> want to launch and hit enter. You can use Ctrl+Space or Ctrl+Tab to
> switch between the switcher and the launcher, or when there are no
> open windows matching a name but there are apps the mode is switched
> automatically.
>
> You can customize the look and feel and functionality in the
> preferences.
>
> Extension Homepage: https://github.com/daniellandau/switcher
>
> Shell version: `3.38` (newest) ... `3.14` (oldest)

To bind the common keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> with this extension, user may be required to use a workaround. A GitHub user, PHLAK, has submitted [this issue #63 on GitHub](https://github.com/daniellandau/switcher/issues/63) and also explained the workaround in several comments:

> I would like to bind the Switcher to Super + Tab but am unable to. I've also noticed I cannot bind it to Alt + Tab either.
>
> ---
>
> I was able to work around this by setting the value directly with `dconf`:
>
> ```
> dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/switcher/show-switcher "['<Super>tab']"
> ```
>
> You can also do the same by using the `dconf-config` GUI.
>
> ---
>
> You might also have to unbind any pre-configured shortcuts using that key combination. Specifically, "Switch applications" is bound to `Super+Tab` in Gnome.
>
> You can change this by opening the Settings and navigating to `Devices > Keyboard`. Then Search for `Super+Tab` and change or remove this binding.

**Disclaimer**: The original author did not test this extension because not using a GNOME desktop. This answer simply quoted the most seemingly reliable resources found on the web. The screenshot was redone and optimized (122kB) in GIMP instead, because the original screenshot and the animated image were too large (500kB, 7MB).

**TL;DR** Go to the GNOME Shell Extensions website and install the extension of choice: [Switcher by dlandau](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/973/switcher/). Subject to compatibility with the Shell version.

---

**Answerer's note**: Included longer comments that explained how this answer fits to the question. One comment that replied to OP query at the time remained as it is, below this answer.

[Ubuntu 18.04 uses GNOME Shell 3.28](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-shell&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), so the extension is supposedly compatible -- Feb 14 '19 at 19:32

The described feature is something similar to the traditional smart launcher i.e. Kupfer, GNOME Do, or Launchy: press Alt- or any assigned shortcut, then display a launcher window pop-up (requires to type to find opened windows). In contrast, the Shell extension will display a launcher window pop-up that readily show list of opened windows. The typing or using cursor keys is only required for switching to the target window (the only missing criteria). -- Feb 26 '19 at 13:10

In short: the extension "Switcher by dlandau" will display a simple list of the window titles, but does not switch between windows with the same Alt-Tab. That is the closest you can get on GNOME with Shell extension to this date. -- Feb 26 '19 at 13:24

Comment: This is a great answer. But does it fit to the above question? The app you talk about does this: "Switch windows or launch applications quickly by typing". The question is about a simple list of the window titles to switch between windows with alt-tab.

Comment: Initially, I found ["Openboxy Alt-Tab by sharat87"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/848/openboxy-alt-tab/) that fits perfectly to the question; however, this extension is unmaintained and compatible with only Shell version 3.10. Hence this answer suggested "Switcher by dlandau" as the closest alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are specifically looking for "Cycling through windows in a list" feature that is available in Window Manager Tweaks->Cycling in XFCE.

[ALT-TAB Cycling in a List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Mpm.png)

[image]

Comment: Up to now I am using the default gnome desktop of Ubuntu 18.04. AFAIK xfce is not running on my desktop. Could you please elaborate your answer. Do I need to install linux mint first?

Comment: No, you would not need to install linux Mint, as XFCE is only a desktop environment as are Gnome,KDE,LXDE etc. You can even do one better, and simply add XFCE to your current Ubuntu distro while keeping your current Gnome, and if give XFCE a try to see if you like it more than Gnome and if not you will be able to switch back fairly seamlessly.

Comment: Oh I forgot to include the most important thing, namely the command to run to install XFCE packages. `$sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xfce4 `. Once packages are installed, reboot, and when you see the login screen you will have another option (likely there will be a drop down combo box near the button to login) to select as far as your desktop environment for the session.

Comment: could you please elaborate the consequences this has? If I use xfce, what other things change? I guess I am not running gnome any more.

Comment: 1, the most noticeable consequence will be visual. Your desktop environment will look different than the current look of Gnome/Unity but you should be able to get used to it fairly quickly. 2. XFCE has the enormous advantages of being very fast, light, and very stable. I actually still have it running on a very old laptop that only has a single core (the other core overheated and went dead) 1.2 GHz Athlon laptop with only 1GB RAM and 5400 HDD without a single issue, and there is no interfacing delay whatsoever. 3. XFCE is highly customizable.  If you want a functionality, you can add it.

Answer (score 4):

#### Textual Alt Tab

A late home-cooked one:

*[In action](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5njujtfqwvm0kj/vokoscreen-2019-02-18_10-20-02.mkv?dl=0)*

[image]

#### How to set up

The setup exists of two tiny scripts, to be saved into one and the same directory:

#### script 1

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck, Gdk
import subprocess

css_data = """
.activestyle {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: white;
}
.defaultstyle {
  border-width: 0px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
"""

class AltTabStuff(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        # css
        self.provider = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
        self.provider.load_from_data(css_data.encode())       
        Gtk.Window.__init__(
            self, title="AltTab replacement"
        )
        self.curr_index = 0
        self.connect('key-press-event', self.get_key)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
        self.set_decorated(False)
        buttongrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(buttongrid)
        self.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)

        wins = get_winlist()
        self.buttonindex = 0
        self.buttonsets = []
        index = 0
        for w in wins:
            button = Gtk.Button("\t" + w.get_name())
            button.set_relief(Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE)
            buttongrid.attach(button, 0, index, 1, 1)
            index = index + 1
            button.connect("clicked", raise_window, w)
            self.buttonsets.append([button, w])
        self.set_focus()
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def set_focus(self):
        for b in self.buttonsets:
            button = b[0]
            self.set_style(button, active=False)
        newactive = self.buttonsets[self.buttonindex][0]
        self.set_style(newactive, active=True)
        n_buttons = len(self.buttonsets)
        self.buttonindex = self.buttonindex + 1
        if self.buttonindex >= n_buttons:
            self.buttonindex = 0

    def set_style(self, button, active):
        st_cont = button.get_style_context()
        if active:
            st_cont.add_class("activestyle")
            st_cont.remove_class("defaultstyle")
        else:
            st_cont.remove_class("activestyle")
            st_cont.add_class("defaultstyle")
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider(
            st_cont,
            self.provider,
            Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION,
        )

    def get_key(self, val1, val2):
        keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(val2.keyval)
        if keyname == "Tab":
            self.set_focus()
        elif keyname == "Alt_L":
            window = self.buttonsets[self.buttonindex-1][1]
            button = self.buttonsets[self.buttonindex-1][0]
            raise_window(button, window)
        elif keyname == "Escape":
            Gtk.main_quit()


def raise_window(button, window):
    subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ia", str(window.get_xid())])
    Gtk.main_quit()

def check_windowtype(window):
    try:
        return "WNCK_WINDOW_NORMAL" in str(
            window.get_window_type()
        )
    except AttributeError:
        pass

def get_winlist(scr=None):
    """

    """
    if not scr:
        scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
        scr.force_update()
    windows = [w for w in scr.get_windows() if check_windowtype(w)]
    return windows


AltTabStuff()
```

#### script 2

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dr=`dirname $0`
f=$dr'/alttab_runner'

if ! pgrep -f $f
then
$f
else
echo "runs"
fi
```

*Do the following steps:*

1. Make sure both `Wnck` and `wmctrl` are installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-gi gir1.2-wnck-3.0 wmctrl
   ```
2. Save script 1 into an empty file as (exactly) `alttab_runner`, script 2 as (exactly) `alttab_alternative`. *make both scripts executable*
3. Disable the existing Alt-Tab:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications '[]'
   ```
4. Set the shortcut (exactly) Alt-Tab to run script 2:

   ```
   /path/to/alttab_alternative
   ```

#### Usage

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to call the switcher (as in the picture), release Alt and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the windows, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> again to pick the selected window from the list.

<kbd>Escape</kbd> will dismiss (close) the switcher.

#### Options

If you'd like different colors, you can play with the css in script 1 to set your own styling.

[image]  [image]

To do so, edit this section, where `activestyle` is obviously the currently selected item:

```py
css_data = """
.activestyle {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: white;
}
.defaultstyle {
  border-width: 0px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
"""
```

See for Gtk css options [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html) on font and buttons.

## EDIT

If you'd like to stick to *exactly* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, in the exact key behaviour as the usual one, use instead of script one:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dr=`dirname $0`
user=$USER
f=$dr'/alttab_runner'
trg='/tmp/'$user'_alttab_trigger'

if ! pgrep -f $f
then
$f
else
echo "runs"
touch $trg
fi
```

And instead of script 2:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck, Gdk
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
import time
import os

trigger = os.path.join("/tmp", os.environ["USER"] + "_alttab_trigger")

css_data = """
.activestyle {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: white;
}
.defaultstyle {
  border-width: 1px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
"""

class AltTabStuff(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        # apply css
        self.provider = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
        self.provider.load_from_data(css_data.encode())       
        Gtk.Window.__init__(
            self, title="AltTab replacement"
        )
        self.curr_index = 0
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)
        self.set_decorated(False)
        buttongrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(buttongrid)
        self.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)

        wins = get_winlist()
        self.buttonindex = 0
        self.buttonsets = []
        index = 0
        for w in wins:
            button = Gtk.Button("\t" + w.get_name())
            button.set_relief(Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE)
            buttongrid.attach(button, 0, index, 1, 1)
            index = index + 1
            button.connect("clicked", raise_window, w)
            self.buttonsets.append([button, w])
        self.set_focus()

        # thread to watch the trigger file
        self.timer = Thread(target=self.wait)
        self.timer.setDaemon(True)
        self.timer.start()

        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def set_focus(self):
        # rotate the focus + styling
        for b in self.buttonsets:
            button = b[0]
            self.set_style(button, active=False)

        newactive = self.buttonsets[self.buttonindex][0]
        newselected = self.buttonsets[self.buttonindex][1]
        time.sleep(0.03)
        self.set_style(newactive, active=True)
        n_buttons = len(self.buttonsets)
        self.buttonindex = self.buttonindex + 1
        if self.buttonindex >= n_buttons:
            self.buttonindex = 0
        return newselected

    def wait(self):
        """
        wait loop; see if trigger file pops up, or we need to quit on immediate
        key release
        """
        newfocus = self.buttonsets[0][1]
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.05)
            if not self.key_checker():
                # try/except, in case no windows on workspace
                try:
                    self.activate(str(newfocus.get_xid()))
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                Gtk.main_quit()
            if os.path.exists(trigger):
                os.remove(trigger)
                newfocus = self.set_focus()

    def activate(self, arg1, arg2=None):
        # activate the selected window, close preview window
        w = arg2 or arg1
        subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ia", w])
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def set_style(self, button, active):
        st_cont = button.get_style_context()
        if active:
            # st_cont.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_SUGGESTED_ACTION)
            st_cont.add_class("activestyle")
            st_cont.remove_class("defaultstyle")
        else:
            st_cont.remove_class("activestyle")
            # st_cont.remove_class("suggested-action")
            st_cont.add_class("defaultstyle")
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider(
            st_cont,
            self.provider,
            Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION,
        )


    def key_checker(self):
        # check if keys are in a pressed state
        exclude = ["Button", "Virtual", "pointer"]
        keyboards = [
            k for k in get(["xinput", "--list"]).splitlines()
            if not any([s in k for s in exclude])
        ]
        dev_ids = [[
            s.split("=")[1] for s in k.split() if "id=" in s
        ][0] for k in keyboards]
        pressed = False
        for d in dev_ids:
            if "down" in get(["xinput", "--query-state", d]):
                pressed = True
                break
        return pressed


def get(cmd):
    # just a helper
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, TypeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
        pass


def raise_window(button, window):
    subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ia", str(window.get_xid())])
    Gtk.main_quit()


def check_windowtype(window):
    try:
        return "WNCK_WINDOW_NORMAL" in str(
            window.get_window_type()
        )
    except AttributeError:
        pass


def get_winlist(scr=None):
    if not scr:
        scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
        scr.force_update()
    windows = [w for w in scr.get_windows() if check_windowtype(w)]
    return windows


AltTabStuff()
```

Setup is exactly as the first version:

1. Make sure both `Wnck` and `wmctrl` are installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-gi gir1.2-wnck-3.0 wmctrl
   ```
2. Save script 1 into an empty file as (exactly) `alttab_runner`, script 2 as (exactly) `alttab_alternative`. *make both scripts executable*
3. Disable the existing Alt-Tab:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications '[]'
   ```
4. Set the shortcut (exactly) Alt-Tab to run script 2:

   ```
   /path/to/alttab_alternative
   ```

Comment: @DKBose Ah, sorry, I was editing exactly at the same time! accidentally overwrote your edit.

Comment: Hi @DKBose not at my box atm, but did you by any chance forget to make the python script executable or forgot to include the shebang? Both scripts *need* to be. Looks like bash is trying to interprete python code. No imagemagick involved of course.

Comment: @DKBose could you run the python scrip with `python3 script`? Again: the error message even isn't python error code.  Bash is trying to run the python code.

Comment: @DKBose Yep, What I thought, please check your python shebang. You might have missed one character.. Exactly getting your message when I remove `!#/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Okay, just so you know how much I know about coding … The problem was that I copied the code from your answer into the script and that included Ask Ubuntu's four spaces at the **start of each line** to signify code. Once I got rid of those spaces, your script works! Sorry for the false alarm!

Comment: @DKBose Haha, no problem, glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

With [alttab](https://github.com/sagb/alttab) (`alttab -mk Control_L -vertical -t 1300x30 -i 1x1 -bg '#aaaaab' -frame '#597b8d' -fg '#000000' -font "xft:DejaVu Sans Condensed-8"`):

[image]