# Asking for tool that effectively jump between windows

Tags: gnome-shell, window, application-switcher, productivity

Most of the time I use mouse / <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to select windows in working screen. I don't think it's a convenient way.

Is there any other effective way/tool that help quickly jump between windows?

I'm especially looking for some tools that select windows by name (like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, type "chrom", jump to Google Chrome).

[Autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump), found in currently supported Ubuntu repos, does an excellent work on changing directory command line, but I cannot find this kind of tool for working windows.

Comment: What if you have multiple Google Chrome windows in your example?

Comment: I've suggested [Rofi](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117948/248158). In that link, typing "git" and pressing Enter would open that particular window Chrome window because GitHub is a unique item in that list. Rofi allows the user to rapidly filter out non-related windows. I'm assuming there'll be some way, based on the title or application, to distinguish between open windows.

Comment: By the way, look at [jumpapp](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp) reviewed [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/run-or-raise-application-windows-on.html).