# On KDE, how to set up keyboard shortcut to show all open windows?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde

There is a (top-right) hot corner action set up by default, that shows previews of all open windows. I can find it under Settings > Desktop behaviour > Screen edges, and then the top-right edge is linked to an action, and it's called "Present windows - All desktops".

But that subcategory in settings doesn't have an option to assign a keyboard shortcut to it; And under the category for "Shortcuts", there is no option that has the words "windows" or "desktops"...

So would it be possible to assign a keyboard shortcut, such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, to do what the top-right hot corner does, which is show all my open windows? And if so, how?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1085193/248158

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do the following images help?

Ensure "Present Windows" is active:

[image: Present windows checked in Desktop Effects]

Set a shortcut of your choice or use the suggested default (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>):

[image: Keyboard shortcut to present windows]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System Settings > Window Management > Task Switcher
2. Unselect "Virtual desktops" under "Content"

Comment: its probably located elsewhere. not in "Window Management "