# How to change shortcut to switch windows in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, plasma-5

Most of the shortcuts for switching windows are misconfigured here.
I am using Kubuntu 20.04 with KDE Desktop.
I want to reconfigure the shortcuts for changing windows.

I searched possibilities for this in Global Shortcuts> KWin> Switch ...

and found posibilities to switch beetween Windows left, right, above and below (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left, right, above or below</kbd>).

I expected to find the option to switch to the last window there (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Where is this? How can I configure this?

Ideally, I'd like use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch direct to the last visited window.

[image]

My System:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions you're looking for are named **Walk Through Windows...** They are located in System Settings at Shortcuts | Global Shortcuts | KWin.

[image: shortcuts]

Note: Search for "walk" or "window" instead of "tab", shown in the screenshot. Searching for "tab" works on my computer because I have it set to use alt+tab, while on your computer, they're "misconfigured".

---

You can also configure the shortcuts in the Task Switcher settings, located at Window Management | Task Switcher.

[image: task switcher]

Comment: Probalby interesting for some is the Ctrl-F10 Key [KDE keyboard shortcut  "present windows all desktops"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130113/1017209)