# Show the Task Switcher on the center of the desktop

Tags: plasma

I am working on KDE plasma 5.

When strike <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch applications, they are displayed on the left side of the screen.

How could enable them to be displayed on the center of screen like in Gnome?

The Task Switcher settings don't provide such an option.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLZxRtyaqQ8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By

> they are displayed on the left side of the screen,

I assume you're referring to something like this:

[image: Previews on the left side of the screen]

To change that, open *System Settings > Window Management > Task Switcher*

In there, there are just too many settings to describe in detail. The [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLZxRtyaqQ8) provided by [mook765](https://askubuntu.com/users/590937/mook765) goes into great detail.

For your purpose, avoid choosing *Breeze* or *Breeze Dark* in the image below.

[image: Avoid Breeze or Breeze Dark]

Whether you wish to have *Show selected window* checked or not is your preference.

But here are images illustrating the task switcher in the center of the screen. (The images are cropped and don't show the full screen.)

**Small icons**

[image: Small icons]

**Large icons**

[image: Large icons]

**Thumbnails**

[image: Thumbnails]

**Informative**

[image: Informative]

**Compact**

[image: Compact]

**Text only**

[image: Text only]

---

There are some related options described in [Is there an alternative task switcher to KRunner which is focused exclusively on window switching?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085193/248158).

Comment: Large icons or compact, most useful on low RAM systems.

Comment: NOTE also, sort order,  is a good to know for different workflows.