# KDE Plasma - ways to manage opened programs

Tags: kde, plasma

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.10 with KDE Plasma and the Sweet theme.

What are the ways to manage open windows in Plasma? I don't see any bar that lists open windows.

Is there a "go to window" shortcut, where I can input a substring of a window's title and jump to that window?

Comment: Re. "I can input a substring of a window's title and jump to that window?" https://askubuntu.com/a/1117948/248158 ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the output of `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep -i composit`. The reason is that `Ctrl+F9` needs compositing to work. In a normal Kubuntu, compositing can be toggled with `Shift+Alt+F12`.

Comment: Re. "I don't see any bar that lists open windows.", see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161386/show-the-task-switcher-on-the-center-of-the-desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> zooms out and shows all open windows. Common keystrokes are listed at https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html

You may find more useful information at https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html and 
https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Windows_Management

Comment: Sadly Ctrl+F9 doesn't seem to do a thing, even though it's assigned to "Toggle Present Windows (current desktop."

Comment: I wonder if OP has somehow disabled compositing. Compositing is necessary for several desktop effects, including `Ctrl+F9`, to work.

Comment: Correct, compositing was disabled. I heard `Shift+Alt+F12` disables all animations. Is there a way to disable all animations, while still having the compositor requiring functionalities enabled?

Comment: @JohnSmith Ask a new question and please limit each question to one specific issue.